# Qual a diferença entre os sanitizadores e validadores em PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Qual a diferença entre `FILTER_VALIDATE` e `FILTER_SANITIZE` em PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como o nome diz, [`FILTER_SANITIZE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) limpa o dado removendo caracteres indesejados de acordo com o critério daquela sanitização escolhida, mas ele não indica se é válido ou não. Ele mexe no dado.

Já [`FILTER_VALIDATE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) valida se o dado é válido ou não, de acordo com o critério daquela validação escolhida. Ele responde como está o dado.

Em muitos casos ambos devem ser usados, mas depende do que deseja. Já que a sanitização não garante a validade, então a primeira deve ser seguida da segunda para garantir que está limpo e válido.

A validação só deve ser usada se só precisa de um "sim ou não" porque mesmo válido o dado pode não estar totalmente limpo (ainda que costume acontecer).